# tensorflow scope lost in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-lab

I'm having trouble splitting up tensorflow code that runs fine in 1 cell in jupyter lab (v2.1.5). As a simple test I did this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a=2
print(a,tf.__version__)
```

result:
2 2.3.0-rc0

cell2:

```
print(a)
print(tf.__version__)
```

result:

2

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d9c2549c3ca0> in <module>
      1 print(a)
----> 2 print(tf.__version__)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

Any toughts what's missing?

Comment: That's really odd. Are you sure you are not assigning anything to `tf` in between the cells? I would also check the kernel output in the console where jupyter lab was started.

Comment: I'm absolutly sure that I only executre these 2 cells. I did found a workaround though. If shut down the kernel and then restart (so not just restart), it works as expected.